# Unable to serve hugo theme after update; getting "error calling partial:execute of template failed: error calling delimit: can't iterate over <nil>"

Tags: github-pages, hugo

I'm trying to update my blog which uses the `hugo-coder` theme. I've tried updating the submodule that I had added, post the upgrade when I run the `hugo server` command, I get the following exception :

```
Change of config file detected, rebuilding site.
2021-03-15 22:01:46.390 +0530
ERROR 2021/03/15 22:01:46 render of "taxonomy" failed: execute of template failed: template: _default/list.html:11:9: executing "_default/list.html" at <partial "csp.html" .>: error calling partial: "/Users/ishabbi/PlayGround/rookieBlog/themes/hugo-coder/layouts/partials/csp.html:1:269": execute of template failed: template: partials/csp.html:1:269: executing "partials/csp.html" at <delimit .Site.Params.csp.childsrc " ">: error calling delimit: can't iterate over <nil>
ERROR 2021/03/15 22:01:46 render of "term" failed: execute of template failed: template: _default/list.html:11:9: executing "_default/list.html" at <partial "csp.html" .>: error calling partial: "/Users/ishabbi/PlayGround/rookieBlog/themes/hugo-coder/layouts/partials/csp.html:1:269": execute of template failed: template: partials/csp.html:1:269: executing "partials/csp.html" at <delimit .Site.Params.csp.childsrc " ">: error calling delimit: can't iterate over <nil>
ERROR 2021/03/15 22:01:46 render of "term" failed: execute of template failed: template: _default/list.html:11:9: executing "_default/list.html" at <partial "csp.html" .>: error calling partial: "/Users/ishabbi/PlayGround/rookieBlog/themes/hugo-coder/layouts/partials/csp.html:1:269": execute of template failed: template: partials/csp.html:1:269: executing "partials/csp.html" at <delimit .Site.Params.csp.childsrc " ">: error calling delimit: can't iterate over <nil>
ERROR 2021/03/15 22:01:46 render of "term" failed: execute of template failed: template: _default/list.html:11:9: executing "_default/list.html" at <partial "csp.html" .>: error calling partial: "/Users/ishabbi/PlayGround/rookieBlog/themes/hugo-coder/layouts/partials/csp.html:1:269": execute of template failed: template: partials/csp.html:1:269: executing "partials/csp.html" at <delimit .Site.Params.csp.childsrc " ">: error calling delimit: can't iterate over <nil>
ERROR 2021/03/15 22:01:46 failed to render pages: render of "page" failed: execute of template failed: template: _default/single.html:11:9: executing "_default/single.html" at <partial "csp.html" .>: error calling partial: "/Users/ishabbi/PlayGround/rookieBlog/themes/hugo-coder/layouts/partials/csp.html:1:269": execute of template failed: template: partials/csp.html:1:269: executing "partials/csp.html" at <delimit .Site.Params.csp.childsrc " ">: error calling delimit: can't iterate over <nil>
Rebuilt in 65 ms
```

The entries for `params.csp` in the `config.toml` file are as follows :

```
[params.csp]
    scriptsrc = ["'self'",
        "'unsafe-inline'",
        "https://platform.twitter.com",
        "https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com",
        "*.amazon-adsystem.com",
        "https://www.google-analytics.com",
        "cse.google.com",
        "https://www.google.com",
        "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com",
        "https://adservice.google.com",
        "https://www.googletagservices.com",
        "jsfiddle.net",
        "www.instagram.com",
        "disqus.com",
        "disquscdn.com",
        "*.disqus.com",
        "*.disquscdn.com"]
```

The content of the csp partial is as below :

```
{{ printf `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content; default-src 'self'; child-src %s; font-src %s; form-action %s; frame-src %s; img-src %s; object-src %s; style-src %s; script-src %s; prefetch-src %s;">` (delimit .Site.Params.csp.childsrc " ") (delimit .Site.Params.csp.fontsrc " ") (delimit .Site.Params.csp.formaction " ") (delimit .Site.Params.csp.framesrc " ") (delimit .Site.Params.csp.imgsrc " ") (delimit .Site.Params.csp.objectsrc " ") (delimit .Site.Params.csp.stylesrc " ") (delimit .Site.Params.csp.scriptsrc " ") (delimit .Site.Params.csp.prefetchsrc " ") | safeHTML }}
```

Can someone please help me with what could be the issue here? The site is served in case I remove the CSP partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so turns  out that I was missing the relevant security policies in my `config.toml` file. I referred to the default config.toml file [here](https://github.com/luizdepra/hugo-coder/blob/master/exampleSite/config.toml)

The config file should've looked somewhat like this :

```
# If you want to implement a Content-Security-Policy, add this section
[params.csp]
childsrc = ["'self'"]
fontsrc = ["'self'", "https://fonts.gstatic.com", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/"]
formaction = ["'self'"]
framesrc = ["'self'"]
imgsrc = ["'self'"]
objectsrc = ["'none'"]
stylesrc = [
  "'self'",
  "'unsafe-inline'",
  "https://fonts.googleapis.com/",
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/"
]
scriptsrc = ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "https://www.google-analytics.com"]
prefetchsrc = ["'self'"]
```

The site now loads after updating my `config.toml` file to include the other security policies.